# Alexander Duality for Relative Homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Is there a formulation for Alexander Duality for pairs of spaces $(A, B)$ such that $A\subset B\subset S^n$?

I can't find a reference for this anywhere, but I think it is as follows, which I arrived at using a pair of long exact homological and cohomological sequences and the five lemma: $$H_k(A,B)\cong H^{n-k}(S^n\setminus B,S^n\setminus A)$$

Is this true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spanier's *Algebraic Topology*, Theorem 6.2.17 (p. 296):

> Let $U$ be an orientation over [a commutative ring] $R$ of an $n$-manifold $X$ and let $(A, B)$ be a compact pair in $X$ [i.e., $A \subseteq X$ is compact and $B \subseteq A$ is closed in $A$]. Then for all $q$ and $R$-modules $G$, there is an isomorphism
>   $$\bar{\gamma}_U: H_q(X - B, X - A; G) \cong \bar{H}^{n - q}(A, B; G).$$

I believe this gives the statement you want (assuming $A$ and $B$ aren't too pathological). Note that Spanier defines
$$\bar{H}^q(A, B; G) = \varinjlim_{(U, V)} H^q(U, V; G),$$
where $(U, V)$ ranges over neighborhoods of $(A, B)$ in $X$.

Comment: I agree thanks! One question, what does the limit of the group over the neighborhoods mean? @Daniel Hast

Comment: The family of all neighborhoods $(U, V)$ of $(A, B)$ is directed downward by inclusion, making $\{H^q(U, V; G)\}_{(U, V)}$ into a direct system of $R$-modules; the limit is the direct limit (i.e., colimit) in the category of $R$-modules. This is explained in more detail in Spanier, 6.1.6 (p. 289).