# Does Alexander Duality commute with inclusion?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

This is a follow up to this question I asked previously: [Alexander Duality for Relative Homology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1070100/alexander-duality-for-relative-homology)

I am working with two compact pairs of spaces $(A,B)$ and $(A',B')$, where $A'\subset A$ and $B'\subset B$, and all of them lay within an orientable n-manifold $X.$ The spaces $A$, $A'$, $B$, and $B'$ are all unions of closed balls, which I believe means that the pairs of spaces are homotopy equivalent to pairs of simplicial complexes and thus the following is true for all $q$:

$$\varinjlim_{(U,V)} H^q(U,V)\cong H^q(A,B)$$.

My question is, does the following diagram commute (I believe it does but cannot figure out if there is a straight forward way of showing so)? All homology groups are over $\mathbb{Z}/2$.

$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{lll}
H_{k}(X-B,X-A) & \cong & H^{n-k}(A,B)\\
\da{i_*} && \da{i_*}\\
H_k(X-B',X-A') & \cong & H^{n-k}(A',B')\\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: You haven't said what pairs (U,V) you consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theorem 5.1 of http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102721108 gives what you want, at least in the setting of simplicial complexes. ("Derived complex" means there just "barycentric subdivision", i.e. you have to consider a sufficiently fine triangulation of the sphere to contain triangulations of A and A'.)